# Replaced infinite switch failed

Tags: electrical, stove

The dual burner (one large one small) was only working on HI  Replaced the infinite switch.  It worked properly for about two weeks.  Now it only works on HI again, both burners

Any sugestions?  Thank you

Comment: What is an "infinite switch"?

Comment: Two switches failing might mean the problem is somewhere else causing the switch to fail/not work right.  Make/model of the stove might help.